# $6$ eigenvalues of a $4\times4$-matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am struggling with determining the eigenvalues of the following (symmetric) matrix:

$$ A =\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix} $$

What I did : $$ \operatorname{char}_X(A) =\det\begin{pmatrix}
2 -X & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 -X & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 -X & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 -X
\end{pmatrix} "=" \det\begin{pmatrix}
2 -X & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & (2-X)^2-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 -X & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & (2-X)^2-1
\end{pmatrix}  = $$ $$=(2-X)^2 ((2-X)^2-1)^2 = 
(2-X)^2 (X-3)^2 (X-1)^2. $$

This yields $6$ eigenvalues. How could that happen? What is wrong here?

Comment: The row operations you are using to reduce the matrix are NOT determinant-preserving.  $r_1 \leftarrow r_1 - c r_2$ preserves the determinant, but $r_1 \leftarrow c r_1 - r_2$ does not.

Comment: Your first $\det$ is good. Work it out and you get $((2-x)^2-1)^2$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asserted equality of two determinants is incorrect.  Let $M$ be the matrix whose determinant appears first; let $N$ be the matrix whose determinant appears after the "equals" sign.

You multiplied the second row by $2-X$.  That alters the determinant.  Then you added $-1$ times the first row to the second, and that does *not* alter the determinant.  Then you did the same in the third and fourth rows.  So you would have
$$
\det M = \frac 1 {(2-X)^2} \det N = (X-3)^2(X-1)^2.
$$

Another thing to be aware of is this:
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B\end{bmatrix} = \det A\cdot\det B.
$$